# Graphing in Stata with a dummy variable

Tags: stata

I'm graphing a regression in Stata with a dummy variable, but my results look like this, which makes sense because obviously the dummy variable is either 1 or 0. But s there a better way to graph this result? This is my current code:

```
graph twoway scatter rating_value late_ind
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps use a bar chart for categorical variables?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/507896.  Check out other forms of visualization, too, including side-by-side boxplots, violin plots, bean plots, etc.