# What jitter value should I use for this scatter plot?

Tags: scatterplot, noise, jitter

I plotted a **scatterplot between humidity and temperature (air) in centigrade.** I got the following graph;

[image]

It is evident that the points fall in discrete columns. This might be because of the rounding of the humidity estimates to one decimal point. To break up these columns, I think some **random noise (jitter)** could be added to the humidity estimates. I want to know **what value of jitter should I use?** The new variable **(jittered humidity) shall be of the form; humidity + jitter.**

Comment: What is the problem that you’re trying to solve with jitter? The data being arranged in those vertical lines is not *inherently* a problem, because it reflects exactly how the data are recorded.

Comment: @Sycorax ; Though it is not inherently a problem, it is probably not how the original data had been collected. The variable has been rounded to 2 decimal points so perhaps adding some random noise will make it look more empirical.

Comment: If your goal is to make some account of the fact that the values were rounded, consider using something like [interval arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic) in your subsequent analysis.

Comment: @Sycorax I would maintain it *is* inherently a problem because the discretization potentially (and almost certainly in this case) creates a great deal of overplotting and thereby can cause the visual impression of regions of greater or less density to be deceptive or even horribly incorrect.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/506611/919 for an illustration.

Comment: BTW, the amount of jitter to use depends on your objective.  It's almost always a good idea to experiment.  Start with the full width of the discretization, then look at substantially less and substantially more jitter.  All three conditions can be useful, even for the same dataset.

Comment: @whuber Your point about the visual impression of density is well-taken. As an alternative, one could leave the data in vertical stacks and use transparency to convey density -- showing that it's not stacks that harm density visualization. Whether or not transparency solves the problem depends on the problem to solve. OP said they're concerned that the data don't "look empirical," so leaving the vertical lines in place wouldn't solve that. (Although I'm not sure that "looking empirical" is a problem that needs solving via plotting -- it sounds like premature rounding is the real culprit.)

Comment: If distance between vertical 'lines' is $w$ then maybe jitter with $\mathsf{Unif}(-w/3,w/3)$ to (mostly) avoid overplotting while still making it clear you're using rounded data. // Similar to suggesting in @whuber's Comment. I have used this and was happy with results.

Comment: @whuber ; I second to your point; "I would maintain it is inherently a problem..." for the graph that is depicted in the question showcases small scatters. It was very difficult to distinguish between these distinct bars with the normal size of the dots.

Comment: @whuber ; What is the "full length of the discretization"?

Comment: In this case, $0.01.$ So, add *iid* uniform noise supported on $[-0.005,0.005]$ (to the horizontal coordinate) as one of your initial attempts at visualization and go from there.

Comment: Thank you @whuber

Answer (score 4):

There is not a unique way to do this, nor is it easy to formalize the space of possibilities here, so here is **one way** to set the jitter.

In your case, there appears to be even spacing between columns of points. For a point from a column of points at $x=a$ you could uniformly sample a new position of that point from $[a - \frac{w}{2}, a + \frac{w}{2}]$ where $w$ is the width between columns of points. This should almost-surely protect the order of points along the horizontal axis between columns while spreading out the values.